# click on OnListItemClick() goto uninstall through Intent

Tags: android

there as a listview that show all app that are install in phone ...now the function OnListItemClick(){

}
when click on app goto uninstall through Intent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//This might fail if the app is not found, so better use it in a try catch block
context.startActivity(i);
```